# Has anyone got graphics working properly on 10.04 on a Sony Vaio P series?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, sony, vaio

A fresh install gives me full native resolution but it's still pretty unusable. Scrolling a browser or page of text is so slow it's forced me back to windows (!). Youtube video is out of the question.

I've also tried netbook edition but same problems (unsurprisingly).

Specifically, I have the Sony VGN-P11Z.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 6):

It's a known problem with the intel GMA 500 that your computer uses. The fix is avaliable in a [ppa](http://code.google.com/p/gma500/wiki/PPARepository). To sum up, type in your teminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install poulsbo-driver-2d poulsbo-driver-3d poulsbo-config
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Javier is right above, but there's some additional fixes, too (especially for 10.10 at least)

Try the end of this thread for 10.10 on Vaio P

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10027642

(I'm also trying to keep this up to date, too, for my personal experience with setting it up at  dumbbunny.org/2010/10/24/sony-p-series-running-10-10-meerkat-ubuntu/  )